# Trouble changing font size in figure legends

Tags: floats, fontsize, etoolbox

I'm trying to set the font size smaller in the legends for all of my figures and tables. The way I was trying to do this was using \AtBeginEnvironment but that doesn't seem to do anything at all. This is a minimal example of what is failing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{relsize}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\smaller}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{whatever}
Text
\end{figure}

Outside text
\end{document}
```

Now that should, I think, make 'Text' appear smaller than 'Outside text' exactly as it would if you put the `\smaller` inside the figure environment. But it doesn't. I tried using the floatrow package instead but it messes up the ordering of the figure caption and the legend text and `\captionsetup` will only alter the caption itself not the legend text.

Any help? Why does `\AtBeginEnvironment` not work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the last things the `figure` enviroment does is issuing the internal command `\@floatboxreset` whose definition is

```
\def\@floatboxreset{%
  \reset@font
  \normalsize
  \@setminipage
}
```

and this is why the `\smaller` declaration has no effect, because the tokens in `\AtBeginEnvironment` are found earlier.

You should instead change the meaning of `\@floatboxreset`

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\small\@setminipage}%
}
\makeatother
```

The change will not leak outside the environment.

In case you're using `setspace`, something more should be done, as the package patches `\@xfloat` to issue again `\normalsize`, which is an error, in my opinion, as `\selectfont` would suffice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\small\@setminipage}%
}
\patchcmd{\@xfloat}{\normalsize}{\selectfont}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{whatever}
Text
\end{figure}

Outside text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, egreg.

However, while that works perfectly in the minimal test environment, it fails to work in my real document. Do you know if any packages would interfere with it?

Comment: Right, I found the responsible package - setspace stops it working - now I just need to figure out why

Comment: Well, it seems that `setspace` messes with the float setup functions so that `\@floatboxreset` never gets called.

By altering your suggestion so that instead of redefining `\@floatboxreset` it does `\apptocmd{\@xfloat}{\small}{}{}` I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @JackAidley I've added a better patch than yours (which would affect also the `table` environment).

Comment: Thanks, egreg. Could you explain why is yours a better way of doing it? I put the `apptocmd` in the `AtBeginEnvironment` to avoid cross-contamination and just duplicated for the `table` environment.

Comment: @JackAidley To begin with, the patch is simpler; moreover it will do what `setspace` should be doing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to redeclare the `@makecaption` command.
First we define the font and size for the caption-Title (figure or table) and the font for the caption-text. Then `\@makecaption` is rewritten:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\textCapTitFont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}  
\newcommand*{\Captionfont}{\small\sffamily}
\makeatletter
    \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
      \vskip\abovedisplayskip\Captionfont%
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\textCapTitFont{#1}~~#2}%
      \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa > \hsize
        \textCapTitFont{#1}~~#2\par                  
      \else
        \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\box\@tempboxa\hfill}%
      \fi
      \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some normal text, not beeing in a caption, just to compare 
\begin{figure}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is an explanation \ldots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The question is not about changing font size in the caption.

Comment: @egreg It seems I missed something. But the fontsize in caption is changed to `\small`. The setting of `\sffamily` can be omitted.

Comment: The question ends with "`\captionsetup` will only alter the caption itself not the legend text". Thus a "legend text" is not the caption.

Comment: @egreg You can change the font for "Figure 1" and "This is an ..." individually, eg. setting `\textCapTitFont` to `{{footnotesize#1} and `\Captionfont` to `\Large`. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: The OP wanted to change the font used in the body of the figure environment, not in the caption.

Comment: @egreg Oh I see, sorry for the misundertanding!