# Why doesn't font family change take effect when using AtBeginEnvironment{figure} together with memoir?

Tags: macros, floats, etoolbox

I'm trying to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}` to customize the font family and font size used in figures. However, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\sffamily\tiny\@setminipage}%
  \patchcmd{\@xfloat}{\normalsize}{\selectfont}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  % \tiny % this works
  test
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on what's happening here?

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that I'm using `memoir`. The solution found in another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64514/) works for setting the font family, but not the size.

Comment: There's a very similar question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64514/trouble-changing-font-size-in-figure-legends In that question `\small` is the command to add, but the solution should be the same. If this helps you, please let us know so that we can close this question as duplicate; otherwise, please tell why the solution doesn't apply to your case.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, knew there would be someone who had had this problem before... Just couldn't find it. =) Well, it now sets the font family, but the size is not affected. Apparently `memoir` is doing something here...

Comment: @gablin No idea what the underlying problem is, but memoir provides its own hooks for floats: `\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\sffamily\tiny}`. There is also `\setfloatadjustment{table}{<code>}`.

Comment: @Audrey: That did it! Can you please write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Audrey That's exactly what I found. Please, add an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memoir class provides its own hooks for floats:

```
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\sffamily\tiny}
```

In general to invoke `<code>` at the beginning of every `<floatname>`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\setfloatadjustment{<floatname>}{<code>}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not using the `memoir` class, the following should work:

```
% Redefine figure environment so that all figures are centered and use tiny sans-serif font
\makeatletter
\let\figureorig\figure
\def\figure@i[#1]{\figureorig[#1]\centering\sffamily\tiny}  % with optional argument
\def\figure@ii{\figureorig\centering\sffamily\tiny}  % without optional argument
\def\figure{\@ifnextchar[\figure@i \figure@ii}  % Redefine depending on presence of [
\makeatother

% Redefine table environment so that all tables are set in tiny sans-serif font
\makeatletter
\let\tableorig\table
\def\table@i[#1]{\tableorig[#1]\sffamily\tiny}  % with optional argument
\def\table@ii{\tableorig\sffamily\tiny}  % without optional argument
\def\table{\@ifnextchar[\table@i \table@ii}  % Redefine depending on presence of [
\makeatother
```

The relatively complicated redefinition results from the fact that the `figure` and `table` environments can carry optional arguments. Thus, the redefinition looks for an opening square bracket “[” in order to determine whether an optional argument is provided or not.